# A blog using Bootstrap and Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, coding-style

I've been stuck for a time now with my commenting system on my blog. I now need you help to solv the problem and push me in the right direction. I'm using Ruby on rails and the twitter open source framework bootstrap.

**show.html.erb:**

```
    <h2>Comments</h2>
 <div id="comments">
         <%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
 </div>

 <%= form_for {@post, Comment.new} do |f| %>
        <p>
                <%= f.label :body, "New comment" %><br/>
                <%= f.text_area :body %>
        </p>
        <p><%= f.submit "Add comment" %></p>
<% end %>

</div>
```

**CommentsController:**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
        def create
                @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
                @comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
                redirect_to @post
        end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Blog2::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, :only => [:create]
  end
```

**comment.html.erb**

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
        <p>
                <strong>
                        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
                </strong>
                <br/>
                <%= comment.body %>
        </p>
<% end %>
```

**model/ comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :body
end
```

**I'm getting errors in show.html.erb for my two (:body) symbols and the form_for line.**

Well this is my first blog and I'm pretty new to RoR, appreciate some help :)

**1st Error:**

```
 SyntaxError in Posts#show

Showing /Users/Jdartland/blog_2/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #23 raised:

/Users/Jdartland/blog_2/app/views/posts/show.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
...  form_for {@post, Comment.new} do |f| @output_buffer.safe_c...
...                               ^
/Users/Jdartland/blog_2/app/views/posts/show.html.erb:29: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
'); end 
       ^
/Users/Jdartland/blog_2/app/views/posts/show.html.erb:32: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting '}'
/Users/Jdartland/blog_2/app/views/posts/show.html.erb:34: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting '}'
Extracted source (around line #23):

20:          <%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
21:  </div>
22: 
23:  <%= form_for {@post, Comment.new} do |f| %>
24:         <p>
25:                 <%= f.label :body, "New comment" %><br/>
26:                 <%= f.text_area :body %>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/show.html.erb

Rails.root: /Users/Jdartland/blog_2
```

**2nd Error**

```
ArgumentError in Posts#show

Showing /Users/Jdartland/blog_2/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #23 raised:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
Extracted source (around line #23):

20:          <%= render :partial => @post.comments %>
21:  </div>
22: 
23:  <%= form_for @post, Comment.new do |f| %>
24:         <p>
25:                 <%= f.label :body, "New comment" %><br/>
26:                 <%= f.text_area :body %>
Rails.root: /Users/Jdartland/blog_2

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/posts/show.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_erb___3910729666325401247_70293324213060'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:26:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"2"}
```

**After following zeantsoi's advice I changed the show.html.erb and _comment.html.erb. This is where I am left with right now 15/6 22.03** ***UPDATED!***

Updated show.html.erb:

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
 <div id="comments">s
         <%= render :partial => 'posts/comment', :locals => {:comments => @post.comments} %>
         <p>
  </div>
</div>

<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <p>
                <%= f.label :body, "New comment" %><br/>
                <%= f.text_area :body %>

        <%= f.submit "Add comment" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**The current Error:**

```
howing /Users/Jdartland/blog_2/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #28 raised:

undefined method `body' for #<Comment:0x007f88611a1738>
Extracted source (around line #28):

25: <%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
26:   <p>
27:                 <%= f.label :body, "New comment" %><br/>
28:                 <%= f.text_area :body %>
29:         
30:         <%= f.submit "Add comment" %>
31:   </p>
Rails.root: /Users/Jdartland/blog_2

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/posts/show.html.erb:28:in `block in _app_views_posts_show_html_erb___3992012847724603598_70111860057680'
app/views/posts/show.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_erb___3992012847724603598_70111860057680'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:26:in `show'
```

Comment: Please post the errors, and in general when you make a post on S/O regarding some error

Comment: Post your routes.rb as well

Comment: My routes.rb are posted :), sure have gotten many errors though, 1 sec

Comment: @varatis there's the Errors :) This is only my second post here on stack ^^

Comment: You need to learn the syntax of the Ruby language :]

Comment: Have you run your migrations? `rake db:migrate`?  Even though your model for `Comment` shows the `:body` field, I suspect you might be missing that information in the database.  Try running migrations or check in `db/schema.rb` and verify that it knows that the comments table has `body` as a field.  That might solve your last error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to pass a partial path to your `render :partial`, not an object(s):

```
# app/views/posts/show.html.erb (for a partial located at `app/views/posts/_comments.html.erb`
<%= render :partial => 'posts/comments', :locals => {:comments => @post.comments} %>

# app/views/posts/_comments.html.erb
<% comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.content %>
<% end %>
```

Second, in order to send your post to your nested route, you'll need to wrap your `form_for` arguments in brackets, not curly braces:

```
# app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it!  I still get an error though.

Comment: I just realized that my _comments.html.erb is locaded at views/comments/_comments.html.erb sho i changed my partial path to 'comments/comment'. Still getting an error message. (Added to the post).

Comment: @jdartland, I had a small typo in my code which I've now corrected. There needs to be a hash rocket (`=>`) between `:locals` and the locals hash in your partial. Give the amended syntax a try – it should work.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! Solved my error, got another though... One I struggled with b4. I posted it in the post.

Comment: The first post is now updated with the current error it says that my body method is undefied :S Eaven though my comment class has a accessible attribute called "body".

Comment: You are missing the `body` attribute for the `Comment` model. Did you add the attribute when you created the comments migration?

Comment: Maybe but my comment model looks like this : class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :body
end

Comment: You should verify whether or not `body` is actually a model attribute. Adding an attribute as `attr_accessible` doesn't do anything unless there's a corresponding column in your database table. You can verify whether `body` is an attribute by typing `Comment` in the Rails console.

Comment: Thanks sooo much for you help! Rly appreciate it! The body works (added it to my comments model) I dont get any error and the creation of comment works fine but the comments does not display after being created :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves all your problems but in your situation you need to pass an array like this

```
 form_for [@post, Comment.new]
```